# Purpose of __name__ in TypeVar, NewType

Tags: python, python-3.6, type-hinting

In the `typing` module, both `TypeVar` and `NewType` require as a first positional argument, a string to be used as the created object's `__name__` attribute. What is the purpose of `__name__` here?

Considering that this is a compulsory argument, I would expect it to be something essential. In PEP-484 where type hinting was introduced, the argument is normally set as a string of the variable name assigned to the object:

```
T = TypeVar('T', int, float, complex)
```

But, I can't really tell how this end up being used in `typing.py` in `CPython`. Replacing the string with indeed any other string does not appear to break anything in my tests.

Comment: It's equivalent to the classname of a proper class, e.g. the `T` in `class T: pass`. Declaring a TypeVar will not set a classname in the run time, se we help ourselves by giving the nametag that lets us access the TypeVar the exact same name. But, as you correctly noticed, nothing forces us to do that. Does this clear things up, or is your question meant idfferently?

Comment: Hi Arne! Are you familiar with any use cases for setting the name attribute in a certain way? It felt to me as though `__name__` is mostly useful at the module level, where we do imports and the ubiquitous `if __name__ == "__main__": pass`. For class names, I'll have to use that whenever I call or instantiate the class, but for `TypeVar` and `NewType`, this is done via the assigned variable name instead, so within the context of the typing functions, how is the attribute used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `__name__` attribute is the associated typename that the IDE, for example, will use in its type hints. Given the following toy code:

```
T = TypeVar('not_T', int, float)
def test_func(arg: T): pass
```

Calling the function with something incorrect like `test_func('not_a_number')` would result in a type hint like this:

```
Expected type 'not_t', got 'str' instead
```

As far as the python interpreter is concerned, no restrictions are set on conformity between `type.__name__` and the name tag you use to handle it, but other third-party tools such as `mypy` might not accept differing variable name and `__name__`, which is also a requirement in the intitial typing [PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics):

> The argument to TypeVar() must be a string equal to the variable name to which it is assigned. Type variables must not be redefined.

---

For an additional use case, you can also check the types in the `__annotations__` member of any object where it is used to type hint, e.g.

```
print(test_func.__annotations__)
>> {'arg': ~not_T}
```

And use that to implement further type checking or handling in your code - in which case your `TypeVar.__name__`s better be meaningful :)

Comment: This is really useful, it clears up a lot of maybe-s I have about how to use type hinting. Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: for `TypeVar`, the string argument is required to be identical to the variable name, see e.g. [the PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics). This is also enforced by mypy and pyright. (`NewType` has no such documented requirement. It is however enforced by mypy. Pyright currenly doesn't enforce this.)

Comment: @Carl thanks for pointing that out, I included it in the post.