# Why does TypeVar and TypedDict require repeating the variable name as a string?

Tags: python, type-hinting, static-analysis, python-typing, typing

In Python typing, why do I have to write `T = TypeVar("T")` instead of just `T = TypeVar()`? Any static analyzer is able to read the variable name without requiring the string parameter. The string parameter only matters for getting the name of the type variable in runtime. As far as I know, this is only used in the type variable `repr`:

```py
>>> T = TypeVar("T")
>>> S = TypeVar("U")
>>> T
~T
>>> S
~U
```

There are two (related) things I'd like to understand:

1. In what context would I need this `repr`? Specifically, because of type erasure, the `repr` will never tell me anything about the actual *value* of the type variable, only its *name*. I've never seen this name used for anything in runtime, even for debugging or introspection purposes. In what kind of situations is it useful?
2. Why is the runtime name mandatory (not only by convention, but as a type-checking rule)? If I don't care about runtime behaviour of the type variable, why am I required to even *specify* a runtime name to it, and why would this name be tied to the name of the runtime variable the `TypeVar` is assigned to?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48417985/13454049

Comment: Thanks for the link! I don't think it quite answers my question, though. For example, apparently when it was answered there was no binding between the type var `__name__` and the name of the Python variable. Also, it mentions the `~T` repr, but it doesn't explain how it would actually be useful in real life.

Comment: @fonini that binding existed at that time too (PEP484 was settled in 2015 - three years before), the linked post just fails to answer the question with correct and typecheckable examples...

Comment: It is **really** interesting... I found [Guido notes from 2014](https://quip.com/r69HA9GhGa7J), where `TypeVar` was called `Var` (renamed later in [github issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1)), and it still required name as a first argument. It may be just an artefact of ancient solutions, which remained just as a convenience. In addition to debugging/repr points above, I can mention pickling. Type annotations are pickled together with objects, AFAIC, and having distinct `__name__` for every TypeVar in module (they can't repeat!) may allow for better pickling without more magic.

Answer (score 3):

Especially for debugging, it's good to be able to know *which* type variable you're dealing with when a type variable ends up somewhere it shouldn't. For example, if you end up with a type variable in a list, or if some code gets passed a type variable somehow when it was supposed to be working with a real type object, it's way more useful if `print`ing it gives at least some hint of which type variable you're working with, instead of just telling you "this is a type variable". (You can also check which module it comes from by inspecting its `__module__` attribute, although this is unfortunately completely undocumented.)

It's also good for interactive exploration. If you examine a class and find it's generic in `Key` and `Value`, or `Shape` and `Dtype`, that tells you a lot more than if you find it's generic in `<typing.TypeVar object at 0x7fb64d197a00>`.

Even if there weren't immediate, concrete use cases for having a name available at runtime, they still probably would have put in the name argument just for consistency, and in case any future use cases came up.